# how to use vector to store a shape?

Tags: c++, vector, graph, lib

I first create a window, and I create a series of rectangles and put them into a vector, then comes to the problem. The code can not build. But I don't know why. Is that I can not use vector in this way"vector rect;"

```
#include <vector>
#include<string>
#include "Graph.h" // get access to our graphics library facilities
#include "Simple_window.h" 
int main()
{

Graph_lib::Point tl{ 100, 100 }; 

Simple_window win{ tl, 1000, 800, "Simple Window" }; 

int x_size = 800;
int y_size = 800;

using namespace std;
vector<Graph_lib::Rectangle> rect;//error
for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < x_size&&y < y_size; x += x_grid, y += y_grid)
{
    Graph_lib::Rectangle r(Graph_lib::Point(x, y), x_grid, y_grid);
    r.set_fill_color(Graph_lib::Color::red);
    rect.push_back(r);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    win.attach(rect[i]);
win.attach(grid);
win.wait_for_button(); 

return 0;
}
```

D:\Visual Studio Community 2017\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xmemory0(856): error C2280: 'Graph_lib::Rectangle::Rectangle(const Graph_lib::Rectangle &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

```
D:\VS_practice\ChengLu_C13Drill\include\Graph.h(311): note: compiler has generated 'Graph_lib::Rectangle::Rectangle' here

D:\Visual Studio Community 2017\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\vector(958): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,const _Ty&>(_Alloc &,_Objty *const ,const _Ty &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Alloc=std::allocator<Graph_lib::Rectangle>,
            _Ty=Graph_lib::Rectangle,
            _Objty=Graph_lib::Rectangle
        ]

D:\Visual Studio Community 2017\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\vector(958): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,const _Ty&>(_Alloc &,_Objty *const ,const _Ty &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Alloc=std::allocator<Graph_lib::Rectangle>,
            _Ty=Graph_lib::Rectangle,
            _Objty=Graph_lib::Rectangle
        ]

D:\Visual Studio Community 2017\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\vector(981): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<T,std::allocator<_Ty>>::emplace_back<const _Ty&>(const _Ty &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=Graph_lib::Rectangle,
            _Ty=Graph_lib::Rectangle
        ]

D:\Visual Studio Community 2017\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\vector(980): note: while compiling class template member function 'void std::vector<T,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(const _Ty &)'
        with
        [
            T=Graph_lib::Rectangle,
            _Ty=Graph_lib::Rectangle
        ]

D:\VS_practice\ChengLu_C13Drill\src\main.cpp(32): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::vector<T,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(const _Ty &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=Graph_lib::Rectangle,
            _Ty=Graph_lib::Rectangle
        ]

d:\vs_practice\chenglu_c13drill\include\std_lib_facilities.h(72): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<T,std::allocator<_Ty>>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=Graph_lib::Rectangle,
            _Ty=Graph_lib::Rectangle
        ]

D:\VS_practice\ChengLu_C13Drill\src\main.cpp(27): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Vector<Graph_lib::Rectangle>' being compiled

D:\VS_practice\ChengLu_C13Drill\include\Graph.h(311): note: 'Graph_lib::Rectangle::Rectangle(const Graph_lib::Rectangle &)': function was implicitly deleted because a base class invokes a deleted or inaccessible function 'Graph_lib::Shape::Shape(const Graph_lib::Shape &)'

D:\VS_practice\ChengLu_C13Drill\include\Graph.h(232): note: 'Graph_lib::Shape::Shape(const Graph_lib::Shape &)': function was explicitly deleted
```

Build failed.

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory, as Fred Larson noted.   You need to read the documentation for the "Graph_lib" to understand why `Rectangle` is not copyable (i.e. has a deleted copy constructor).

Comment: So, how can I correct this code? I mean how to print out a series of rectangle ? If the vector does not work.

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Another question. I add "win.attach(r);win.wait_for_button();" in the loop, but the rectangles just show one by one, and nothing show up in the end. I don't know why. I just want all these rect show up together.

Comment: for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < x_size&&y < y_size; x += x_grid, y += y_grid)
 {
  Graph_lib::Rectangle r(Graph_lib::Point(x, y), x_grid, y_grid);
  r.set_fill_color(Graph_lib::Color::red);
  win.attach(r);
 }

Comment: That needs to be a new question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question amounts to "why can't this third-party (non-standard) non-copyable type be stored in a standard container which can only store copyable objects?".  The OP needs to read documentation for the third-party library to understand why this type is non-copyable, and to find alternatives.  People without access to the third-party library cannot do that.    As such, this question is off-topic in a C++ forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the `Graph_lib::Rectangle` class is not copyable, because its copy constructor is deleted. This prevents you from using `push_back()` directly on an instance. You might be able to use `std:move()`:

```
rect.push_back(std::move(r));
```

It's possible the class is not moveable either. In this case, you could use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) in the vector:

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<Graph_lib::Rectangle>> rect;
```

This will require you to dynamically allocate your objects. This can be done using [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) if your compiler supports the C++14 standard or later:

```
for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < x_size&&y < y_size; x += x_grid, y += y_grid)
{
    auto r = std::make_unique<Graph_lib::Rectangle>(Graph_lib::Point(x, y), x_grid, y_grid);
    r->set_fill_color(Graph_lib::Color::red);
    rect.push_back(std::move(r));
}
```

If C++14 is not available, you can allocate your rectangles using `new`:

```
for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < x_size&&y < y_size; x += x_grid, y += y_grid)
{
    auto r = std::unique_ptr<Graph_lib::Rectangle>(new Graph_lib::Rectangle(Graph_lib::Point(x, y), x_grid, y_grid));
    r->set_fill_color(Graph_lib::Color::red);
    rect.push_back(std::move(r));
}
```

Comment: well, but it says that"std has no member 'unique_ptr'".

Comment: You'll need `#include <memory>`.

Comment: in the second one, it says that "cannot convert from 'Graph_lib::Rectangle *' to 'std::unique_ptr<Graph_lib::Rectangle,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' "

Comment: It should be fixed now.

Comment: it says that :error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<Graph_lib::Rectangle,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function

Comment: Ah, my mistake. You have to [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) the pointer into the vector.

Comment: sorry, I don know what you mean,could you show me. sorry, I am a fresh man.

Comment: See my edit. Actually, if `Graph_lib::Rectangle` is moveable, you wouldn't need `std::unique_ptr` at all.

Comment: But another problem shows up. It about "win.attach(rect[1]);" in the end. 
    error C2664: 'void Graph_lib::Window::attach(Graph_lib::Widget &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::unique_ptr<Graph_lib::Rectangle,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' to 'Graph_lib::Shape &'

Comment: Your vector members are pointers now. So you'll need to use `->` instead of `.` and use the unary `*` to dereference the pointer in other places, like `win.attach(*rect[1])`.

Comment: you mean "win->attach(rect[1]*);" this way?

Comment: No, exactly like I said. `win.attach(*rect[1])`. We didn't make `win` a pointer, just members of the vector. so `rect[1]` is now a pointer. `*rect[1]` dereferences the pointer.

Comment: YES! It works now! THANKS a lot! Besides, my English name is also Fred, cool name,cool guys.

Comment: Glad to have helped. The best thanks on SO is upvoting and accepting the answer that helped you.